# Приходит непонятный ответ от сервера Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Я отправляю запрос в методе getStaticProps, но в ответ мне приходит какая-то жесть в неправильной кодировке, хотя в хуке useEffect и Postman всё приходит нормально. В чём проблема?

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
const firstCategory = 0;
const res = await axios.post<MenuItem[]>(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN + '/api/top-page/find', {
    firstCategory
}, {
    responseEncoding: 'utf8'
})

return {
    props: {
        menu: res.data,
        firstCategory
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы заходите напрямую в порт или через веб-сервер? Что резолвится в content-encoding?

Comment: Ето оштбка в аксиосе вот уже ответили https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74583264/nextjs-axios-does-not-decode-data-value-on-the-server-side/74595343#74595343